# How to integrate the Jaxb2Marshaller in the Spring integration route?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-oxm

1. Created the Jaxb2Marshaller object.
2. Need to convert a java POJO to XML (Marshalling).

Need help in integrating Jaxb2Marshaller in the Integration Route.

Code flow:-

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() throws JAXBException {
        return from(...).
                .enrichHeaders(...)
                .handle(...)
                .transform(processor()::generateXml)
                .channel(...)
                               .get();
    }
```

How can I add Jaxb2Marshaller in transform() step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an out-of-the-box transformer to use:

```
.transform(new MarshallingTransformer(jaxbMarshaller()))
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/xml.html#xml-marshalling-transformer

How to create a `Jaxb2Marshaller` you can consult Spring Framework docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#oxm-jaxb2

Comment: I don't see that transformer in spring-integration-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar, is it removed ?

Comment: It is a part if the `spring-integration-xml` module. So, you need to add that dependency in your project

Comment: Could someone help me with a Jaxb marshal issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68031311/java-lang-illegalstateexception-marshaller-must-support-the-class-of-the-marsha